# How do I create a card on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, onclick, card

I am a few days into learning React JS. It's been very interesting and simplifies JavaScript, at least how I view it. My goal at the moment is to create a button that when clicked will create a new card with a random number generated in the card.

I can't figure out how to add the onClick= functionality for it to work the way I'm envisioning it. At the moment I have the code for the button written on my index.js file. index.js is my main file, it is where my App component is located. I see people use a file named App.js, not sure why, but that's another question for later.

Currently my buttons are stylized the following way.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <body>
      <header>
        <div className="ui buttons">
          <button className="ui button mb-1 mt-1">
            <i className="plus icon"></i>
            Add Card
          </button>
          <div className="or mb-1 mt-1"></div>
          <button className="ui positive button mb-1 mt-1">
            <i className="sort numeric down icon"></i>
            Sort All
          </button>
        </div>
      </header>
```

They are located in a header container at the top of my page. It looks like this following image.

[image: Add Card or Sort All Buttons Header]

I want to be able to click the Add Card button and then for it to create a new card in my card container. As picture below.

[image: Card Container w/ Add Card or Sort All buttons visible.]

The current card you see in the above image is hard coded at the moment. I created a MainCard.js component that houses the code for the card including the functionality of the randomly generated number and the styling.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import React from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

let getRandomNumber = function (min, max) {
  let getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
  return getRandom;
};

const MainCard = () => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Button
        className="ui mini red basic icon button"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "0",
          right: "0",
        }}
      >
        <i
          className="red x icon"
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            top: "0",
            right: "0",
          }}
        ></i>
      </Button>
      <Card.Body>{getRandomNumber(0, 101)}</Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default MainCard;
```

Previously I was doing the onClick functionality in my AddCard.js but for some reason the Alert I created was both being generated when the page was being reloaded as well as when the button was clicked. I couldn't figure out the reasoning for this and it has become a wall that I haven't been able to climb over yet. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple, but I just can't figure out what that is. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't see your alert.

Comment: The alert was removed, it is not currently present in the code I provided above.

Comment: It's confusing to include it in your question if you aren't using it.

Comment: I included it as an example of what I have tried. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

For example.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [{items}, setItems] = useState({ items: [] });
  const addItem = () => {
    items.push(<div key={items.length}>Hello</div>);
    setItems({ items: [...items] });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addItem} />
      {items}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This creates a persistant storage that you can set values into that remain between component rebuilds. The object in storage has a single key "items" with an array containing the items. It is convenient to put your state in an object with a key that describes the contents. This allows you to tell what state object you are looking at if you need to debug your app.

The addItem() callback will add a new item into the object in state. Importantly, the item has a key attribute that should be unique. This helps react monitor the state of elements in an array.

You can see a demo of the above code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-fast-8be2i)

Comment: In the return <div> <button> you show {...items}, is this where I would add my MainCard.js component that houses the design of the card? For example <MainCard />

Comment: This example creates a button that will continually add new items to a list. If you only want a single card, add it in addItem(), then make sure to disable or remove the button when the card has been added.

Comment: I was spreading the items because I forgot that wasn't how react works. You don't need to worry about the spread operator (...).

Comment: You're amazing. Yeah it's working how the code demo shows. I added my MainCard component in place of the Hello text. So now it creates the cards but it's creating within the button. Then I realized that I can remove the {item} after the button like you show up there, add my text, which in this case is Add Card and move the {item} down to my card container. It works perfectly. You have helped me so much I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on Charles Bamford's response, you'll have to use the useState method. The useState method creates a variable and a method to set the value of this variable. Everytime you change a state (using it's setter) React will check the code and re-render everywhere it was used. You will need something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]); // instantiate cards as a empty Array

  const addCard = () => {
    // create a new array with the old values and the new random one
    const newCards = [...cards, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)];

    setCards(newCards);
  };

  const removeCard = (cardIndex) => {
    // create a new array without the item that you are removing
    const newCards = cards.filter((card, index) => index !== cardIndex);

    setCards(newCards);
  };

  return (
    <body>
      <header>
        <div className="ui buttons">
          <button className="ui button mb-1 mt-1" onClick={() => addCard()}>
            <i className="plus icon"></i>
            Add Card
          </button>
          <div className="or mb-1 mt-1"></div>
          <button
            className="ui positive button mb-1 mt-1"
            onClick={() => addCard()}
          >
            <i className="sort numeric down icon"></i>
            Sort All
          </button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main>
        {cards.map((cardNumber, index) => (
          <MainCard number={cardNumber} onRemove={() => removeCard(index)} />
        ))}
      </main>
    </body>
  );
};
```

With an array like this [10, 15, 33], the cards.map will do something like this for you:

```
  <main>
    <MainCard number={cards[0]} onRemove={() => removeCard(0)} /> // 10
    <MainCard number={cards[1]} onRemove={() => removeCard(1)} /> // 15
    <MainCard number={cards[2]} onRemove={() => removeCard(2)} /> // 33
  </main>
```

We are passing the "number" and the "onRemove" function from the App component to the MainCard component. Now we just have to get it from our props, like this:

```
const MainCard = (props) => {
  const { onRemove, number } = props

  return (
    <Card>
      <Button
        className="ui mini red basic icon button"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "0",
          right: "0",
        }}
        onClick={() => onRemove()}
      >
        <i
          className="red x icon"
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            top: "0",
            right: "0",
          }}
        ></i>
      </Button>
      <Card.Body>{number}</Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default MainCard;
```

Comment: I'm testing out your solution as well but I am getting back an error. Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I'm searching for solutions online but haven't been able to find one that solves the problem. Any idea what it could mean?

Comment: This is the initial value right? const [{ cards }, setCards] = useState([]); so it will see the values as an empty array. Wouldn't .map work then?

Comment: It works now. I saw the updated code above and tested it out.

Comment: Can you explain what the removeCard function is? Is it supposed to remove the cards? At the moment it's just replacing the int with a new one.

Comment: Sure. I saw that your cards have a remove button, so you'll have to pass it from your App component to your MainCard component. The way that you so that is by passing it on your MainCard component, like this:
<MainCard onRemove={() => removeCard(index)} />
In your MainCard component you'll have to get it from the props, like this:
const MainCard = ({ onRemove }) => {
  return (
And then you call it on your remove button:
<Button onClick={() => onRemove()}>

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to use the removeCard function